# Passing a function to a child

Tags: polymer-3.x, lit-element

The code is pretty straightforward: I'm try to pass the function `addContactFn()` from `MainComp` to `SideMenu`. On click I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.value.handleEvent is not a function

```
class MainComp extends LitElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.addContactFn = this.addContactFn.bind(this)
    }
    addContactFn() {
        console.log("clicked");
    }
    render(){
        return html`
<div class="main-page">
   <side-menu addContactFn="${this.addContactFn}"></side-menu>
</div>
`
    }

}


class SideMenu extends LitElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
    static get properties(){
        return {
            addContactFn: Function
        }
    }
    render(){
        return html`<a @click="${this.addContactFn}">Add contact</a>`
    }

}
```

Comment: Attribute values are *always* strings: https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/writing-templates#bind-to-attributes

Comment: this code is from the Udemy Polymer course..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Thad said, attributes are always strings, and there's no real safe efficient way of parsing a function in execution

However, you don't really even need to use that, just pass the function as a property rather than as an attribute and that should be enough, here's how MainComp's render would end up after that

```
render(){
  return html`
    <div class="main-page">
     <side-menu .addContactFn="${this.addContactFn}"></side-menu>
    </div>
    `;
}
```

Basically, you just add a dot before the property name

For more info check [LitElement's guide](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/templates#bind-properties-to-child-elements)

Then again, this way of doing stuff is very React-ish and not really recommended for Web Components, you should probably just create a emit a custom event in the child component and pick it up in the parent

Comment: Thanks. It works! is there a real difference between properties and attributes?

Comment: @alfredopacino Attributes are set in html, and they can only be strings, properties are part of the js object, so they can be pretty much anything, what litelement's static properties getter does is to create a mapping between attributes and properties for you so that handling the syncronization between both is easier

Comment: adding a "." in front of any attribute throws an error? How is it possible to get around that?